# How to test fragment in Robolectric Unit Testing in android studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

In my project,first screen is login screen than fragment with recylerview, on clicking recylerview item, fragment get replace and next fragment appears containing recyler view.How to write test cases for unit testing using roboelectric. I am using roboelectric for the first time.Please help me.

Below is my code for loginScreen Test cases class

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,packageName = "com.project.app")
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class LoginScreenActivityTest {
    LoginScreenActivity activity;
    @Test
    public void a_loginPriceguide() throws Exception {
        activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(LoginScreenActivity.class);
        assertEquals("abc@gmail.com",activity.getUsername(0));
        assertEquals("abc123$",activity.getPassword(0));
        CheckBox remember_me = (CheckBox) activity.findViewById(R.id.remember_me);
        remember_me.performClick();
        Button btn = (Button)activity.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btn.performClick();
    }

 @Test
    public void b_loginDialog() throws Exception{
        activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(LoginScreenActivity.class);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            Intent i = new Intent(activity,MainActivity.class);
            activity.startActivity(i);

        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
```

This is what i have done for login screen test cases,and this class is working fine.

But fragment with recylerView gives Null Pointer exception

Code for fragment test cases

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,packageName = "com.project.app")
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ProductTest {
    private Product fragment ;
    private LinearLayoutManager mockLayoutManager;
    ActivityController<FragmentActivity> activityController;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockLayoutManager = Mockito.mock(LinearLayoutManager.class);
        fragment = new Product();
    }
    @Test
    public void l_clickProduct() throws Exception {
        activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity.class);
        activityController.create().start();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        assertThat(layoutManager).isEqualTo(mockLayoutManager);
}
```